# Why is the question about common bugs causing a "page not found" error?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ping-pong question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84920/ping-pong-question)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438347/most-common-one-line-bugs-in-c/) was added to my favorites. Yesterday it was ok, but today it is not working anymore. What happened?

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate):  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/page-not-found-broken-link

Comment: Hi @Shadow. I read the duplicate you gave. It doesn't seems like the same subject. Thanks.

Comment: I said "maybe".. it discuss the same subject of question that was valid and alive and suddenly give "Page not found" error - in that case, question was deleted by OP for his own personal reasons, in this case by moderator because it's off topic. Related. :) (for the record, I didn't vote to close or flagged - just wanted to let you know of that other question)

Comment: Hi @Jeff, yes it is a exact duplicate of that one. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It got deleted by a moderator; you need [10k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to view it on SO.

**Edit**: it was migrated to the Programmers SE site: [http://
programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/62302/most-common-one-line-bugs-in-c](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62302/most-common-one-line-bugs-in-c)

Comment: My gosh! That is really bad. So many useful information there! Please, if that is not some really illegal stuff, bring it back to life.

Comment: @Dr Beco, you can find it at programmers site, since it looks better there.

Comment: Yep, 56 upvotes, 39 answers.... wonder why such question get deleted??

Comment: @YOU - but when migration happens the question should be **Closed**, not **Deleted**.. or has it changed?

Comment: @Shadow, looks something happened, when migrated, programmer site kicked back according tim message at [revision log](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5438347/revisions). so he deleted and locked at SO

Comment: @YOU You need 10k to see the revision log too

Comment: @Michael, heh, yeah, here is screen shot http://i.imgur.com/6ObA8.png

Comment: What do @YOU mean by "kicked back"? Never heard of this before.. ?

Comment: @Shadow, My understanding is the programmers site migrated back to SO. That word was used by moderator Tim Post, I am not sure I am using it correctly. please take a look screen shot http://i.imgur.com/6ObA8.png

Comment: Kicked back because the question was off topic for both sites and doesn't belong. Unless you want to foster more campfire questions. @sha

Comment: @random I see. Well, got my own reservations maybe I'll start new discussion soon. Thanks for clearing this out! :)

Answer (score 1):

The question has been **deleted** and hence showing you that message. Only users above 10000 rep will be able to see that question and reason for deletion.